# DbCommand generates SQL in a date format that MySQL does not accept

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a `DbCommand` created as such.

```
DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
```

I then create `cmd.CommandText` of the format.

```
"Insert into myTable (`Id`,`myDate`) values (@p0,@p1)"
```

When dealing with the second parameter (after creating the first) I have code of the form.

```
var p2 = command.CreateParameter();
p2.ParameterName = "@p2";
p2.Value = myDateTimeObject; //not a string but an actual DateTime object
command.Parameters.Add(p2);
```

In my code I have the following section to execute `DbCommand` variables.

```
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I actually execute this, it successfully creates the following statement but this statement errors when MySQL tries to execute it.

```sql
Insert into myTable (`Id`,`myDate`) values (1,'27/08/2018 16:50:30')
```

And when I look at the error it is the following.

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '27/08/2018 16:50:30' for column 'myDate' at row 1 0.000 sec

Is there anything I can do to ensure it runs with valid SQL that MySQL will accept? I'm happy to provide more information if necessary.

Comment: values (1,DateTime.Parse("27/08/2018 16:50:30"))

Comment: Please run this command `desc your_table_name` and add result to your answer

Comment: try setting the paramether dbtype to datetime

Comment: There are still few items that are not clear here. What .Net provider you use for MySql? What table column definition? I think, your provider or the data is the issue. I just tested it and it works fine. DateTime should be no issue, whatever locale there is. Its a datetime, not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're running in a non-`en-US` locale, and are encountering [MySQL bug #80011](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80011).

One workaround would be to format the `DateTime` yourself in a format MySQL Server can understand:

```
var p2 = command.CreateParameter();
p2.ParameterName = "@p2";
p2.Value = myDateTimeObject.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss'.'ffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
command.Parameters.Add(p2);
```

The other workaround would be to switch to a different MySQL ADO.NET connector that doesn't have this bug, such as [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/).

Comment: Is this mySql's **real issue**? Date time supposedly some kind wild numeric type that should have no issues  storing whatever you throw at it? And the only issue should be if you try to save d/m/yyyy vs m/d/yyyy if you pass it as string? I see how this can happen while saving string but date... this is real issue for mySql as I see it

Comment: @T.S. According to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80011 it's a verified bug in MySQL Connector/NET.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply, I wrote this question last thing on Friday at work. That worked a charm, thank you. I saw elsewhere a potential solution of using the class `MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime` and then using the code  `p2.Value = new MySqlDateTime(myDateTimeObject)`. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Last time I used `MySqlDateTime`, Connector/NET failed with a different exception: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91199 Again, this is something that's fixed in MySqlConnector: https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs

Comment: Okay, thanks. It looks like this connector is not the best maintained judging by the status of the two reported bugs, I'll investigate the suggested one.